# Indefinite article with a noun in the plural: "(a?) dedicated 4 years"

Tags: indefinite-article

Which is the correct version (or are both correct?):

> accrued through dedicated 4 years in IB

or

> accrued through a dedicated 4 years in IB

Comment: Please show what research you have done so far. One of them is wrong but could be corrected by swapping the positions of two "words".

Comment: I did not find the answer anywhere on the web hence the post here. I think you are hinting at- ' through 4 dedicated years in IB.' I think I will go with this one. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @AanchalS That is correct. We don't use an article for the plural indefinite (we can optionally use "some" if we don't specify an amount). So, if it were only one year, we would say "a dedicated year."

Comment: Yes, that it was I was thinking. Forgive me for making you work through it :o)

Comment: @BobRodes But don't we in this case? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252173/indefinite-articles-used-with-plural-nouns-it-was-an-amazing-two-days/252465

Comment: @WillCrawford Forgiven with gratitude ;) Thanks for tickling those grey cells.

Comment: @userr2684291- Thanks. That's why the confusion. Have seen the use of 'a' and 'an' to specify plurals many times... usually for adding flair to the text.

Answer (score -1):

They are both incorrect. **4 years** is not a noun, so you shouldn't apply adjectives to it. You can either move the adjective to the noun:

> accrued through 4 dedicated years in IB

or use a different noun:

> accrued through a dedicated, four-year term in IB

Comment: Counter-example: "It had been a long four years, but he was finally done with college."

Comment: So could you then say, "He attended a long four classes, but he was finally done with college?" You gave a counter-example but didn't provide any source to show that it is correct and why.

Comment: [Here's an ngram plot of a similar pattern with inches as the unit instead of years](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+good+*+inches). "Class" is not a unit of measurement, which I presume is why that doesn't work.